# Is it possible to implement an HTTP proxy using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?

Tags: java, http, proxy

Is it possible to implement an HTTP proxy using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?
Based on the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html), I understand that in order to provide handlers for requests, I have to provide a mapping between a "context" and a handler.
However, the syntax of the context strings seems to preclude HTTP requests that include a full URL, rather than just a pathname component, i.e. the type a proxy has to handle.

(Note: the com.sun.net.httpserver package is [documented as part of Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/index.html) since Java 6; it's not at all clear that it's an unsupported, internal package...)

Comment: You should not base your code on something in the com.sun.* packages, since this is considered internal and may change at any time.

Comment: @BetaRide you are right depending on the purpose of the project; if the purpose is for learning, I don't see problem

Comment: I cannot ensure you; but seems to be OK to implement . but it's also seem to be a hard work. Maybe you will get some difficult with cookies.. things like that.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the syntax of the context strings seems to preclude HTTP requests that include a full URL, rather than just a pathname component

Despite the examples given, and with the proviso that `com.sun` packages don't have the same compatibility guarantees as the rest of Java, you can call `createContext` with a path of `/` and your handler will receive requests with full URIs.

In testing, `http://test` wasn't accepted, but `http://test/` with a trailing slash was. This doesn't seem like something suitable for production use, but it may be acceptable for your purposes.